# Rails Devise - Define separate root paths for signed in user and anonymous user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want the `root_path` of a signed_in user to be `dashboard` and users that are not signed in user to be `index`.

I am using Devise and I know there is a helper `user_signed_in?` but I dont understand how to use it for this purpose.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
unauthenticated :user do
  root :to => 'main#index'
end

authenticated :user do
  # Rails 3 syntax
  # root :to => "main#dashboard"   
  # Rails 4 requires the 'as' option to give it a unique name
  root :to => "main#dashboard", :as => "authenticated_root"
end
```

This is the mechanism provided by Devise for re-rooting authenticated users.

The `root :to => 'main#index'` line is the standard line that Rails places in your `config/routes.rb` when the application is first created.  You can wrap it in the `unauthenticated :user do .. end` block to make certain that it applies to users that are not logged in.

This gives definitive root routing for all users, based on whether they're logged in.

Comment: Could you please precise how visitors will be routed to `index`? Maybe with a root directive outside the `authenticated` block?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in application controller (`application_controller.rb`)

```
protected
def authenticate_user!
if user_signed_in?
  # navigate the user to dashboard
else
  # redirect to index
end
```

This method can then be invoked from other controller(s) using `before_filter`
Example:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```